# Assign certain score according to words

Tags: c#

**Thanks Solved.**

My `words.txt` file looks like the following :

```
await   -1

awaited -1

award   3

awards  3
```

The values are tab-delimited. First, I want to get the result of, for example, await = -1 point and provide score for every sentence from my comment.txt file according to the `words.txt` file. The output of the program should be like (for example)

```
-1.0

2.0

0.0

5.0
```

I am stuck and does not know what exactly I should do next. I only managed to read the `words.txt` file so far.

```
    const char DELIM = '\t'; 
    const string FILENAME = @"words.txt"; 

    string record;  
    string[] fields; 

    FileStream inFile; 
    StreamReader reader; 


    inFile = new FileStream(FILENAME, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    reader = new StreamReader(inFile);

    record = reader.ReadLine();

    //Spliting up a string using delimiter and
    //storing the spilt strings into a string array
    fields = record.Split(DELIM);

    double values = double.Parse(fields[1]);
    string words = fields[0];
```

Comment: This question is too broad. You should narrow it down to a specific problem, rather than asking how to write the entire program.

Comment: What are the contents of `comment.txt`? How are you going to find scores there? What input parameters do you have? There is a huge amount of important questions you haven't even touched

Comment: Just wondering am I on the right track I am trying to make the fields[0] = field[1]. For example words is equal to certain point but I am stucked

Comment: Try to use no txt but xml. Best approach. Other approach: csv file. If You want to stick to txt, You must read about the topics Read line from file and string operations

Comment: You need to read in your comments.txt file then for each word in your words.txt file search for matches in the comments file and keep a running total of points. Is the format something you're stuck with like an assignment, because there are better ways to do this.

Comment: I am trying to make a sentiment analysis using c#. The contet of the comment.txt for example: "Today is a good day" good=2 point so the output will be 2

Comment: Don't wipe out your entire question just to put "thanks..solved".

Answer (score 1):

you should have a look at [dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) you could match each word you want to put a score on with his value in the dictionary. This way you could just loop all the word you got and output the value

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        dictionary.Add("await", -1);
        dictionary.Add("awaited", -1);
        dictionary.Add("award", 3);
        dictionary.Add("awards", 3);

        //read your file
        //split content on the splitter (tab) in an array

        for(int i=0; i<array.Length; i++)
        {
            //output the value
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you feel like using regex approach, try this

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(FILENAME, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
  using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream)) {
    String record = streamReader.ReadLine();
    foreach (String str in record.Split('\t')) {
      Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(str, @"[^-?\d+]", String.Empty));
    }
    streamReader.Close();
  }
  fileStream.Close();
}
```

Tested with words.txt

```
await -1    awaited -1  awaited -1  award 3 award 2 award 1 award 3 awards 3
```

Comment: Oh wait, if u need that decimal thingies, replace inside foreach steatement with

      Int32 i = Int32.Parse(Regex.Replace(str, @"[^-?\d+]", String.Empty));
      Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.0}", i));

Comment: Lose the `.Close();`s as the `using` statements take care of that for you.

Comment: I noe 'using' statement calls close(). I think last time i read msdn states its not gonna throw error. I use this to call an error in my try blocks. Last time, i had problem with memory type class in using statement where it actually didnt close it.

Answer (score 0):

Combining both vadz's answer and im_a_noob's answer, you should be able to read your words.txt file and put it into a dictionary.

```
    Dictionary<string, double> wordDictionary = new Dictionary<string, double>();
    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(FILENAME, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
            {
                int lineCount = 0;
                int skippedLine = 0;
                while( !reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string[] fields = reader.ReadLine().Split('\t');
                    string word = fields[0];
                    double value = 0;
                    lineCount++;

                    //this check verifies there are two elements, tries to parse the second value and checks that the word 
                    //is not already in the dictionary
                    if (fields.Count() == 2 && double.TryParse(fields[1], out value) && !wordDictionary.ContainsKey(word))
                    {
                        wordDictionary.Add(word, value);
                    }
                    else{
                        skippedLine++;
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Total Lines Read: {0}", lineCount));
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Lines Skipped: {0}", skippedLine));
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Expected Entries in Dictonary: {0}", lineCount - skippedLine));
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Actual Entries in Dictionary: {0}", wordDictionary.Count()));

                reader.Close();
            }
            fileStream.Close();
        }
```

To score the sentences you could use something like the following.

```
    string fileText = File.ReadAllText(COMMENTSTEXT); //COMMENTSTEXT = comments.txt
    // assumes sentences end with a period, won't take into account any other periods in sentence
    var sentences = fileText.Split('.'); 

    foreach( string sentence in sentences )
    {
        double sentenceScore = 0;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> word in wordDictionary)
        {
            sentenceScore += sentence.Split(' ').Count(w => w == word.Key) * word.Value; 
        }

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Sentence Score = {0}", sentenceScore));
    }
```

Comment: Just want to ask  how do you to test whether the word and values is stored in the wordDictionary property?

Comment: depends on how thorough you want to be and how long your words list is.  You could trace out the entries after they have been added to see that it is working correctly, but that becomes difficult to see when you have a large number of entries.  A better solution would be to have a counter of the number of lines read and a counter of number of lines skipped, then compare the difference of those to the count of elements in the dictionary.

Comment: Updated my answer to include simple checks on the lines read vs the entries in the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

A working solution without a dictionary:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions; 

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var comment in File.ReadAllLines(@"..\..\comments.txt"))
            Console.WriteLine(GetRating(comment));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static double GetRating(string comment)
    {
        double rating = double.NaN;

        var wordsLines = from line in File.ReadAllLines(@"..\..\words.txt")
                         where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(line)
                         select Regex.Replace(line, @"\s+", " ");

        var wordRatings = from wLine in wordsLines
                          select new { Word = wLine.Split()[0],  Rating = Double.Parse(wLine.Split()[1]) };


        foreach (var wr in wordRatings)
        {
            if (comment.ToLower().Split(new Char[] {' ', ',', '.', ':', ';'}).Contains(wr.Word))
                rating = wr.Rating;
        }

        return rating;
    }
}
```